# Reactjs getting a state value from a child component

Tags: reactjs

React newbie back here with another question (lol). I have a function that returns a generic component and I was wondering if it's possible to get the state value from that component? Here is what I'm trying to do:

EDIT: I've updated some of my code according to responses

```
class CreateTable extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props_;

        this.state = { elements: [] };
    }

    handleCreateTable() {
        var elements = this.state.elements; // []
        elements.push(<TextInput key={"TableName"} label="Table Name" />)'
        elements.push(
                <DataTable
                    tableName = { elements[0].value } // <--- I'd like to do something like this
                />
            );
        this.setState({ elements: elements })
    }
}
```

`TextInput` has a child `TextField`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Be careful about editing your code once there are answers because the answers might no longer make sense. Instead you should strongly consider posting a new question, possibly with a link to your old, related question.

Comment: @Tim you must not put jsx/components in state.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati thanks for the advice. Is there another way I can "insert" a component?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks- I'll do that

Comment: @Tim put them directly in render method. create a seperate function that would return jsx/component and call that function in render.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati iThank you- I'll try that

Comment: @Tim use conditional rendering. Here:https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. Do you want your table name to be dynamic. i.e chage with input value?

Comment: @MurliPrajapati that's correct- What I'm trying to do is take some input table name from a user and display it. However, I'm unsure of how to get the value from my `TextInput`

Comment: I will vote up, now it is good one. But i think it should be another question. because now my answer looks like not from here

Comment: @Tim See my edited answer for some additional tips which address your newest questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do is take some input table name from a user and display it.

The way you could achieve this is by making your `TextInput` component call a function passed by the parent with the current value of the component.

So your `TextInput` might look like this:

```
export default class TextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    const inputText = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      value: inputText
    });
    this.props.onChange(inputText);
  };

  render() {
    return <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleOnChange} />;
  }
}
```

And parent component must pass a function as a prop so that it can know of the changes happening in the child.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableName: ""
    };
  }
  onInputChange = value => {
    this.setState({
      tableName: value
    });
    console.log("I am Parent component. I got", value, "from my child.");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TextInput onChange={this.onInputChange} />
        <span>Table:{this.state.tableName}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`App` component is passing `onInputChange` function to `TextInput` through `onChange` prop. Prop name `onChange` can be anything.

Here is working [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/yj4x87810z) to test this code.

Comment: Thanks a ton Murli! This helped solve my problem :-) Thanks for the quick responses as well

Comment: This helped me out too.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a function that returns a generic component and I was wondering if it's possible to get the state value from that component?

This is not the React way. Instead you should design your components so that the parent keeps all state that it needs. Then the parent passes values from its state as props to its child components.

If a parent component needs to know about events that happen in its children, then you should pass a callback from the parent to the child. Then the child calls this function when an event occurs to notify the parent which can then update its state.

In addition, state should only contain data, not JSX components. You can store a list of data in state and iterate over it in `render()` to create the necessary components. So for example, if you have a method that calls

```
this.setState({items: ['foo', 'bar']});
```

Then in render, you can do something like

```
return <div>
    {this.state.map(item => <DataTable name={item}/>}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for keeping me from going down the wrong path. So what you're suggesting is that for every input component that uses the generic `<Input/>` component, e.g.`<TextInput/>`, `<NumberInput/>`, `<TextField/>` , I should have them maintain their own state?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible, by passing object and setting object attribute in child component

```
const TextInput = props => {
    let holder = {
        getChildState: null
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <TextBox {...props} type="text" multiline={false} id={generateId()} holder={ holder }/>
        </div>
    );
}

class TextBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: null,
        error: false,
        errorMsg: null,
    };

    this.props.holder.getChildState = () => this.state;
  }

  ....
}
```

So if your TextInput would be more complex, than you would use holder.getChildState(), but it would be available only after TextBox constructed.

There is also other possibility to use `emitter`.

But you definitely should be sure what you are doing, because it is more simple and convenient to use only down direction props sharing especially considering that this is `react` philosophy. If you feel that some component should report its state to few other you may try `redux`

Comment: I totally agree. This example is not reallife code example, just a demonstration of javascript possibility